# Execute queries correctly when they don't return rows

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Good morning!

I have a small script that tries to perform an insert operation on a postgres table.

My program that is responsible for making connections to the database is as follows:

```
def conecta_server(lista, names):

    PUERTO      = 5432
    success     = False
    retries     = 0
    max_retries = 10

    while not success and retries < max_retries:

        try:
            with SSHTunnelForwarder((REMOTE_SERVER, 22),
                                ssh_username             = "user",
                                ssh_pkey                 = ssh_pkey,
                                ssh_private_key_password = "",
                                remote_bind_address      = ('127.0.0.1', PUERTO),
                                local_bind_address       = ('', PUERTO)) as tunnel:

                engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passw}@{host}:{port}/{db}".format(
                        user  = 'user',
                        passw = 'pass',
                        host  = tunnel.local_bind_host,
                        port  = tunnel.local_bind_port,
                        db    = 'db'))

                with engine.connect() as conn:
                        dic_df = {name: pd.DataFrame(conn.execute(query).fetchall(), columns = conn.execute(query).keys()) for (query, name) in zip(lista, names)}

            return dic_df

        except Exception as e:
            print('Error al intentarlo...')
            print(e)

        retries += 1
```

I usually use this code for select operations, but as I said, now I need to make an insert.

When I do this the following error occurs:

```
*** sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

The strange thing is that the query is really executed without problem, but when the exception raises the script doesn't leave the while and it is executed 10 times.

Is there any way to avoid this problem? I don't know if the connection can be made with a method other than `fetchall ()`, previously selecting based on the result of the `conn.execute (query) .returns_rows` test.

Thanks you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are retrying your connection so many times.  If you often have difficulty connecting to your database, you should really figure out that issue.

You shouldn't be surprised that it tries ten times - that is exactly what your code does.  It will retry on *any* exception, which is not a great practice.  You should narrow down that exception handler.

Short of re-architecting what you have, you can work around your issue by adding a RETURNING clause to your insert.  This will return data (that you probably don't need), but fetchall won't throw an exception.  This is not the ideal solution, but it should patch things up to at least run.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your answer. Maybe you misunderstood part of my question. I do know that my code tries ten times, I'm not surprised about that. My surprise comes from that despite working correctly, it raises the exception. However, I've just tried your solution and works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Right, it's the fetchall part that is throwing the exception.  So, while the query works, psycopg2 is unhappy about trying to get data back from a query that doesn't return data.  I'm glad that the returning clause worked for you.